# How to keep cursor of a UITextField in focus after dismissing keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard

I am trying to dismiss the OS keyboard and keeping the cursor of the UITextField still in focus, I am trying to do this because I am building a custom stickers keyboard..

So the problem is that after I call the `resignFirstResponder`, the keyboard gets dismissed, witch is a wanted behaviour, but also the cursor gets dismissed, witch I want to keep in focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. However, in simulator you may press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and that will dismiss keyboard but leave focus there (this is a simulation of hardware keyboard). But in general, `UITextField` cannot have a cursor while not being a first responder. If you wish, you can write your custom one

Answer (score 4):

You should have to display a temporary view as the keyboard, and everything else works the way it should.

```
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];    
textField.inputView = tempView; // Hide keyboard, but show blinking cursor
```

It works for `UITextField` and `UITextView` and they need to be set to editable.