# How to Stop Keyboard From Showing When UITextField is Tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

//Xcode 8.3.3 | Swift 3

Disclaimer: Alright, so there are some Q&A on SO that answer this question. However, after extensive Googling, I was not able to find any that are up-to date in Swift (they're all in Objective C and date back to 2010, etc).

I have a project in which I need the user to be able to tap a UITextField and for the blinking line to come up, but I already have a number pad implemented with UIButtons. This means that I do not want the default or any keyboard to come up when the text field is pressed.

[image: Storyboard viewcontroller]

What is the easiest way to achieve this currently?

Comment: This is fairly easy to translate from Objective-C: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208885/1305067

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it would. However I have little to no experience in Objective C, therefore even the seemingly easiest tasks in this area pose a challenge to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this -

```
YourTextView.inputView = UIView()
YourTextView.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
```

this will not open the keyboard but allow cursor blink.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where would I put this code? Putting it into viewDidLoad doesn't seem to do the trick?

Comment: Have you created the outlet of your textfield from your storyboard to view controller class and then tried this on viewdidload

Comment: Ah, the problem was simple: I had user interaction disabled. Thanks, I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer linked by @paulvs translated to Swift 3 would be:

```
let tempView = UIView(frame: .zero)
yourTextField.inputView = tempView
```

Answer (score 0):

try do this:

```
extension YourController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // do some things

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHidden), 
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        return false
    }

    @objc private func keyboardHidden() {
        // disabled keyboard 
        yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```